# How to change my online store template in dbdirector ecommerce platform

Tags: javascript, css, e-commerce, shopping-cart, online-store

Does anyone know how the store template system works in dbdirector? I want to change the CSS of my homepage but I'm not sure where to find the main CSS file. I know there's a way to do it via the backend without FTP. I'm sure I'm just overlooking it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a clear explanation on the DBDirector website -> http://www.dbdirector.com/article/19/3/10/1/10/0/What_is_CSS_and_how_do_I_learn_CSS-

You can either add inline styling :

```
<p style="font-size: 12px">Lorem ispsum</p>
```

Add styling to the HTML page :

```
<style>
p {
   font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
```

or create an external CSS file and include it in the `<head>` of the page

```
<link href="MyStyleSheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I must've completely overlooked that article. That works.